# C# Web API Control requests to end point with FIFO

Tags: c#, api, asp.net-web-api, queue, fifo

I'm trying to think of the best way to explain this

I have an endpoint (Web Api C#) that generates miles.  You pass in two zipcodes.  It takes the two zipcodes and uses a third party dll to get the miles from software that runs on the server.  You have to initialize the dll, set some flags, process the zip codes, then uninitialize the dll for it to work every time. The problem happens when another request comes in for processing to get miles but the previous process has not uninitialized yet. It will error out.

Im tyring to come up with a queue system. In the past the way I've done it is entered them into a database, have a windows server run every 5 seconds to look for any miles that haven't been generated yet but I don't want to have to wait a maximum of 5 second every time I want to get miles from zip to zip.

Can't use google to get miles, has to be this third party software running on our server.  Didn't know if there was a better queue logic that I am just spacing on to process requests coming in while another request is being processed in the API.

Comment: What are you doing to "initialize the dll"?  That sounds really bizarre to me.  Why would need to initialize and uninitialize it every time?

Comment: It sounds strange for me, are you sure that you have to initialize and dispose dll all the time? It's hard to give some more specyfic advice without any code sample. If your solution is based on queues you can use one of thread safe collection ([ConcurrentQueue](https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentqueue-1?view=netframework-4.8)) or you can use [BlockingCollection](https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.blockingcollection-1?view=netframework-4.8).

Comment: Where are the results of these requests - the distance between miles - going? Do clients call the API and wait for a result? It sounds really odd that someone would require you to use something that apparently isn't suited at all for what they want to use it for, but it definitely happens. [MEF is not an IOC container](http://scotthannen.org/blog/2018/12/16/liberation-of-pure-di-mef-is-not-ioc.html).

Comment: There is very little documentation on the API.  And after I have initialized and make a call to the dll, if I call again without unitializing first, an error is thrown.  I'll look in the object browser to see if anything sticks out to maybe "clear" the previous result.

Clients of the API wait for the result.  They are first saved to a database for a local cache to avoid calls to the API for reoccuring zips.

Comment: You all were right with the initialization not needing to happen every time.  Thanks for the help.